# propertyregex removes return characters in multiline

Tags: regex, ant

I'm using ants propertyregex method to change a property and it works fine up to a point. I'm lossing return characters.

Here's what I'm trying to change:

```
cluster.path=\
${nbplatform.active.dir}/harness:\
${nbplatform.active.dir}/platform:\
${nbplatform.active.dir}/nb
```

This is in a .properties file.

So I'm trying to change it like this:

```
<propertyregex property="cluster.path"
               input="${cluster.path}"
               regexp="nbplatform.active.dir"
               replace="xplatform.base"
               global="true"
               override="true"/>
```

The stuff is replaced but I get:

```
cluster.path=    ${xplatform.base}/harness\:    ${xplatform.base}/platform\:    ${xplatform.base}/nb
```

This brakes logic down the line not controlled by me (Netbeans) that uses the ':' as delimiter.

Any idea?

Comment: @javydreamercsw - How are you loading the .properties file?  Also, how are you examining the value of the cluster.path property?  Could you boil this down to a complete build file that illustrates your problem?

Comment: No, I'm trying to change the value itself. I worked around that changing the file itself like this:

<pre>
<replaceregexp file="nbproject/platform.properties"
                       match="nbplatform.active.dir"
                       replace="platform.base"
                       byline="true"
                       flags="g,s"/>
</pre>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around that changing the file itself like this: replaceregexp file="nbproject/platform.properties" match="nbplatform.active.dir" replace="platform.base" byline="true" flags="g,s"/